# How to dynamically add links to a d3 topology?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I took the [sticky force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558) example and tried adding an extra link and updating the layout using `enter()`, but then all the links disappeared and FireBug shows no error either.

Shouldn't these lines have added a link?
`graph.links.push({"source": 0, "target": 11});

link = link.data(graph.links).enter().append("line").attr("class", function(d,i) {console.log(i);return "link";});`

Also, the `console.log(i)` outputs `18` instead of `19`. It's like as though it never took into account the increase in size of the `graph` array.

I checked [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043), but even here it seems like using the `data()` and `enter()` functions should have been enough.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.link {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  cursor: move;
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node.fixed {
  fill: #f00;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var graph =
{
  "nodes": [
    {"x": 469, "y": 410},
    {"x": 493, "y": 364},
    {"x": 442, "y": 365},
    {"x": 467, "y": 314},
    {"x": 477, "y": 248},
    {"x": 425, "y": 207},
    {"x": 402, "y": 155},
    {"x": 369, "y": 196},
    {"x": 350, "y": 148},
    {"x": 539, "y": 222},
    {"x": 594, "y": 235},
    {"x": 582, "y": 185},
    {"x": 633, "y": 200}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source":  0, "target":  1},
    {"source":  1, "target":  2},
    {"source":  2, "target":  0},
    {"source":  1, "target":  3},
    {"source":  3, "target":  2},
    {"source":  3, "target":  4},
    {"source":  4, "target":  5},
    {"source":  5, "target":  6},
    {"source":  5, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  8},
    {"source":  7, "target":  8},
    {"source":  9, "target":  4},
    {"source":  9, "target": 11},
    {"source":  9, "target": 10},
    {"source": 10, "target": 11},
    {"source": 11, "target": 12},
    {"source": 12, "target": 10}
  ]
};

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(40)
    .on("tick", tick);

var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

//d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {

  force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start();
  link = link.data(graph.links).enter().append("line").attr("class", "link");

  node = node.data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 12)
      .on("dblclick", dblclick)
      .call(drag);
//});

console.log(graph.links.length);
graph.links.push({"source": 0, "target": 11});
console.log(graph.links.length);
link = link.data(graph.links).enter().append("line").attr("class", "link");


function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

function dblclick(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
}

function dragstart(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}

</script>
```

Comment: You need to add the link before passing the data structure to the force layout.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff That doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/rkj5cj8d/

Comment: Oh that's what you meant...I converted that section of code to an `addLinks()` function and it works for adding a single link but when I add another link and call `addLinks()` it doesn't http://jsfiddle.net/nav9/dung7n0d/  would like to understand what is going on, rather than just receive a solved answer (if you could spare the time please)

Comment: The problem is that you're resetting `link` and `node` to contain *only* the enter selection, i.e. the new nodes. Set it to contain *all* nodes/links http://jsfiddle.net/dung7n0d/1/

Comment: Thanks that worked, but I thought that `graph.links.push({"source": 0, "target": 11});
link = link.data(graph.links).enter().append("line").attr("class", "link");` was the process of setting it to contain all and links, because I'm setting data to `graph.links`. Please do post it as an answer and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is

```
link = link.data(graph.links).enter().append("line").attr("class", "link");
```

After this, `link` will contain only the links that were just added to the visualisation as you're using `.enter()`. This in turn means that only those will be updated during the `tick` event of the force layout, as you're using the same `link` variable there. It's the same problem for `node`.

To fix, set the selection variables to contain all relevant elements after adding the new elements.

```
link = svg.selectAll(".link");
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dung7n0d/1/).